# PostgreSQL's unaccent function is unable to remove accents (diacritic signs) from Japanese characters like 'ド'

Tags: postgresql, unaccent

The postgresql out of box unaccent function is unable to remove accents (diacritic signs) with more then one diacritic in a character.  The character 'ド' which is failing for normalisation  have 2 diacritic signs in it.

I tried to check the latest version ofhttps://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/unaccent/unaccent.rules but still it does not have mapping for the Japanese characters like  'ド' . Can someone please guide how we can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Like Vérace mentioned in comment, this symbol doesn't have diacritic signs. This is a syllable as Japanese use syllabary instead of alphabet.

That means that while "ト" is "to" in katakana, "ド" is a different syllable: "do".

This is why `unaccent.rules` does not have such mapping. If you need, for some reason, to remove diacritics like *dakuten* (this double dot) anyway, you will have to write your own rules for this function. This way you could reduce other syllables to basic 48 *gojūon* characters.

Answer (score 2):

Strings can be decomposed with Unicode rules by `normalize(text, NFD)` since PostgreSQL 13. In the case of the mentioned string, it produces the following code points:

```
SELECT
  codepoint, 
  to_hex(ascii(codepoint))
FROM
  regexp_split_to_table(normalize('ド', NFD), '') AS codepoint;

 codepoint | to_hex 
-----------+--------
 ト        | 30c8
 ゙          | 3099
```

U+3099 is [Combining Katakana-Hiragana Voiced Sound Mark](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3099), which is in the [Hiragana](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+3040) block. According to this decomposition, there is no diacritical sign in that string, otherwise the code point would be in one of these blocks:

- U+0300 - U+036F Combining Diacritical Marks
- U+1AB0 - U+1AFF Combining Diacritical Marks Extended
- U+1DC0 - U+1DFF Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement
- U+20D0 - U+20FF Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols

If for whatever reason you disagree with that, you may either customize `unaccent.rules` to add your own translations, or if that's impractical, use instead of `unaccent()` your own function like the following, based on the NFD decomposition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_diacritics(text) RETURNS text
AS $$
select regexp_replace (
   normalize($1, NFD),
  '[\u0300-\u036f\u1ab0-\u1aff\u1dc0-\u1dff\u20d0-\u20ff]', -- range of code points to remove
  '',
  'g');
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

Then you can customize the range of code points to remove, according to your local needs.